# What is the most common way to insert new items into a linked list?

Tags: linked-list

I'm learning data structure right now and trying to create some common methods for my linked list class. Since unlike an array, linked list doesn't have an explicit index, I'm wondering do I insert before or after the nth node or a certain value?

For example, if a linked list has the following nodes `{a,b,c,d,e}`. I can insert a new item after `d`, or I can insert a new item after the 3rd node (assume the 1st node has an index 0).

Which of the following two ways is more commonly used?

```
// start from index 0
// insert a new node after nth node
void LinkedList::insert_after_nth_node(int nth, int data) {
    if (nth < length) {
        Node * pointer = head;
        for (int i=0; i <= nth; i++) {
            if(i == nth) {
                Node * newNode = new Node();
                newNode->data = data;
                newNode->next = pointer->next;
                pointer->next = newNode;
            }
            pointer = pointer->next;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Out of boundary!" << std::endl;
    }
}


void LinkedList::insert_after_by_value(int value, int data) {
    Node * pointer = find(value); // find() will return the node that contains the value, or null if value doesn't exist
    if (pointer) {
        Node * newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = pointer->next;
        pointer->next = newNode;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Value doesn't exist in list" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are those different?

Comment: @Confuzing You can insert by index, or the item value. In the example, it's the same thing, since the 3rd node is acutally `d`. Eventually, you will end up inserting the new item after `d`.

Comment: How would you insert into a linked list by index, generally you keep a pointer to only the first item/header and maybe the last element/trailer? How you insert depends on what you are programming. A queue would just insert at the beginning or end, but sorted data you would traverse the list till you find the correct position then insert.